Cannot disable USB Hub in Device Manager
I need to disable USB Mass Storage. I want to disable Generic USB Hub and USB Root Hub (USB 3.0) in Device Manager but when I right-click on them, the option to Disable device does not appear. If I go to Properties -> Device for each device, the option Disable Device is greyed out. Please could someone how may I be able to disable USB Hubs from Device Manager?

There are a number of other ways to disable the USB ports:

Using Regedit, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\USBSTOR and set value Start to 4.


Use the Group Policy Editor to set it disabled. Open Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access, and set Removable Disks: Deny Execute Access to Enabled.

Some BIOS/UEFI settings allow one to disable USB storage.


That said, anyone with Administrator privileges can undo those settings, so to isolate devices more completely, fill the port with cement.
Even so, anyone having physical access to the machine can bypass even that, such as using the speaker and microphone to exfiltrate data, or the LCD screen.
